# Javascript: Call method on object in array of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-loop

I created a class with a method:

```
class MyClass{

myMethod(){
    return ...;
}}
```

After that I push every instance of that class to an array:

```
let myList = [];
myList.push(myClass)
```

How can I call myMethod() within a loop? This code fails:

```
for (var i = 0; myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].myMethod();
}

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myMethod' of undefined
```

Thx,
piccus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should crate an instance with `new` operator in order to call a method:

```js
class myClass{
  myMethod(){
    console.log('hi');
  }
}

let myList = [];
myList.push(new myClass())
myList.push(new myClass())
myList.push(new myClass())
myList.push(new myClass())
myList.push(new myClass())

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].myMethod();
}
```

If you need to call this method without instance, define it as `static`:

```js
class myClass{
  static myMethod(){ // notice static
    console.log('hi');
  }
}

let myList = [];
myList.push(myClass)
myList.push(myClass)
myList.push(myClass)
myList.push(myClass)
myList.push(myClass)

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].myMethod();
}
```

Comment: thank you. The problem was my bad-designed loop. I missed to define a condition to end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of each instance of `MyClass` by pushing `this` into `myList` when the constructor is called. That way you don't have to keep remembering to push into `myList` each time you construct a new `MyClass` instance.

```js
var myList = [];

function MyClass (theAnswer) {
  this.theAnswer = theAnswer;  
  this.getTheAnswer = function () {
    console.log(this.theAnswer);
  };
  
  // Keep track of all instances of MyClass here.
  myList.push(this);
}

new MyClass(42);
new MyClass(null);
new MyClass('Dunno');

for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].getTheAnswer();
}
```